# Expectation values in directional statistics

Tags: probability-distributions

In the context of Variational Bayesian Inference I am facing the following problem:

Let $\alpha$ follow a "von Mises" distribution with mean $\mu$ and concentration $\kappa$. 
Does there exist a formula for the calculation of the expectation values $E \left[ \sin \alpha \right]$ and $E \left[ \cos \alpha \right]$?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Good question.  It's obvious that there's a simple formula for the median value of $\tan\alpha$.  Whether that's also an expected value, I'm not sure, but _if_ it is, then it's clear what the expected value is.  With sine and cosine, on the other hand, it's obvious that they have expected values, and that $E(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)]$ is the median value of $\tan\alpha$.  But the hard part is the expected value of $\sqrt{(E(\cos\alpha))^2+(E(\sin\alpha))^2}$.  For all I know at the moment, that's not all _that_ hard, but it's where most of the work is in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthias: Certainly. $E[\cos\alpha] = r\cos\mu$, where $r$ is the mean resultant length. For the von Mises distribution $r = A(\kappa) = \frac{I_1(\kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)}$, where $I_p(.)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $p$. Similarly, $E[\sin\alpha] = r\sin\mu$.